# Can not remove dropotron transparency on menu dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a CSS template that came with a Dropotron for JQuery menu animation and I am having great difficulty removing the transparency effect on the dropdown menu. For some reason the second dropdown "About Us" is solid. But they both have the same class "opener". I have sifted through the css and jquery.Dropotron-1.0.js attempting to adjust opacity but to no avail. Please help this is the site. http://www.uplandhomesinc.com. You should be able to view all source code easily. Please be nice

Comment: both dropdowns are transparent, in fact About US dropdown is just short and on the white background, add some more option to it, and you'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .dropotron CSS class, change the background :

```
.dropotron {
  background: rgba(32,107,157,0.85);
}
```

to

```
.dropotron {
  background: rgba(32,107,157,1);
}
```

The last value of a rgba color is the transparency. Put it to 1 to make it not transparent at all.

Doc on colors in CSS : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp

Comment: Thank you worked fine of course. I was looking so hard..Thank you much

Answer (score 0):

the background of .dropotron has a transparency color, just replace with :

```
.dropotron {
background: rgb(32,107,157);
...
}
```